# Hp envy battery shows no charge on 18.04, but works well on live session

Tags: 18.04, power-management, laptop, hp, battery

My laptop battery shows 0% charge when logged in to ubuntu and switches off within 5secs of removing the ac power.

However, if I run try ubuntu from a USB drive, I get full battery and it works normally without ac power for a couple hours.
So seems like my battery hardware is alright and fully charged, but the software is reporting it to be always 0% for some reason and hence it switches off when ac power is removed.

Can I fix this somehow? Perhaps configure it to not switch off when battery is 0%?

Also, this a new battery.